# WInforms Chart Control with Multiple Chart Areas Aligned as Tab Page

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, position, alignment

I have chart control with 4 chart areas. Is there way to align/position chart areas like bottom tab control page. One chart is visible at a time. User should navigate the tab pages to to see the charts

Thanks

Comment: If only one ca is visible at a time, why not go all the way and have four charts? - you __could__ have a dummy ca at the bottom and rectangle annotations styled as buttons and use them to manipultate the 4 cas' ElementPositions. Or maybe add buttons styled as Tabs to do the same.. - But a real Tab seems so much easier..

Answer (score -1):

```
private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TbControlFinance.Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons;
    TbControlFinance.ItemSize = new Size(0, 1);
    TbControlFinance.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
}

private void BtnCalendar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TbControlFinance.SelectTab("TabPageDashboard");
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28031079)